# What is the list of key word attribute in InstancedBufferGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

For the [buffer geometry example](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry) here, if I change position to position1, it does not work at all.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
// create a simple square shape. We duplicate the top left and bottom right
// vertices because each vertex needs to appear once per triangle.
var vertices = new Float32Array( [
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0
] );

// itemSize = 3 because there are 3 values (components) per vertex
geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
// I can't change the string 'position' to 'position1', why? 

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Clearly, 'position' is the keyword that is used internally for a list of vertexes. I assume the position will be passed to vertex shader, is this correct?

What are the list of keyword for InstancedBufferGeometry, like the 'position'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [WebGLProgram](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram). Built-in attributes are:

> ```js
> attribute vec3 position;
> attribute vec3 normal;
> attribute vec2 uv;
> ```

Which are the vertex coordinate, normal vector and texture coordinate (There are further attributes for morphing and skinning).

If you use a [ShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial), then you can use Your own vertex and fragment shader, custom attributes and use any name you want.